# Phantomjs w clicking

Tags: button, click, download, phantomjs

I am trying to make a js script to use with phantomjs which:

1. Connects to this page:
   http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/cdio/weatherData/av?p_nccObsCode=136&p_display_type=dailyDataFile&p_startYear=&p_c=&p_stn_num=060062
2. Clicks on the button "All years of data" which refers to an  element and save the zip file to which it redirects.

I don't know which is the function to use in my js. I tried to fetch the url and use wget/curl with cookies but it doesn't work (because it is not pure html), then I tried Jquery with this code (but I don't know what to put inside "button"):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/cdio/weatherData/av?p_nccObsCode=136&     p_display_type=dailyDataFile&p_startYear=&p_c=&p_stn_num=060062', function() {
page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        $("button").click();
    });
    phantom.exit()
});
});
```

What functions do I have to use to do it?

If you can suggest me even some good documentation to understand this language I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

To get to the link you can use one of the following, I prefer the latter:
`$(".downloads li:nth-child(2) a")` or `$(".downloads li:contains('All years') a")`

What you can then do is either click the link (with `.click()` on one of the above) or return the link address (with `.attr("href")` on one of the above), add the base url and download the file with wget.